# VSCode editor textMateRules (in settings.json) fails to re-color attribute

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have been customizing my VSCode editor text highlighting by going into settings.json and playing with the "editor.tokenColorCustomizations". Specifically, there is a textMateRules object that accommodates this customization, and has been working for me in general. But it is mysteriously not working when I try to modify the highlighting for links in my html (meta.attribute.src.html). Here is the settings.JSON bit:

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "textMateRules": [
        {
            "scope": "meta.attribute.src.html",
            "settings": {
                "foreground": "#ff0000",
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I obtained the above scope ("meta.attribute.src.html") by using the "Developer: Inspect Editor Tokens and Scopes" command. It listed these textmate scopes, and I wanted to target the second one:

```
string.quoted.double.html
meta.attribute.src.html
meta.tag.object.img.void.html
text.html.derivative
```

Unfortunately, unlike in the other cases, my settings.json code fails to cause the relevant attribution.rel text to be colored #ff0000 (red). Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    "scope": "meta.attribute.src.html string.quoted.double.html",
    "settings": {
        "foreground": "#7ea4df",
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Curiously, that's not working for me either. (And should it? Wouldn't the code I have above "at least" include anything that fits "meta.attribute.src.html"? My assumption would be that your addition would not expand the scope but only restrict it further? Either way, it's not catching for some reason.)

Comment: Sorry it didn't work for you. In my case this is the only way I got it to work, using "meta.attribute.src.html" only didn't change anything. Same for class names, they don't work for me without adding "string.quoted.double.html". According to this article [link](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/syntax-highlight-guide) the most specific scope is listed at the top, which happens to be "string.quoted.double.html" for src and class.